# How to insert a generic value into an ArrayList and resize it in constant time?

Tags: java, algorithm, generics, priority-queue

To implement PriorityQueue for generic data types with basic methods : insert, delete , head. 
I am facing problems at inserting and I get IndexOutOfBoundsException.

This is the PriorityQueue with the insertion method:

```
public class PriorityQueue<E extends Comparable<? super E>> implements Comparable {
    private ArrayList<E> queue;
    private int size;


    public PriorityQueue(int size) {
        this.size = size;
        queue = new ArrayList<>(size);
    }

    public PriorityQueue() {
        this(50000);
    }

    public void insert(E value) {
        if (queue.size() == size) {
            try {
                throw new SizeLimitExceededException();
            } catch (SizeLimitExceededException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (value == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        if (queue.size() == 0) {
            queue.add(value);
        } else {
            int i;
            for (i = queue.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                if (value.compareTo(queue.get(i)) > 0) {
                    queue.set(i + 1, queue.get(i));
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(i);
            queue.set(i + 1, value);
        }
    }
}
```

It seems that I can't set a new value at array.size index , how can I resize it before adding a new generic data type ?

Comment: This isn't going to be constant time. A sorted-list priority queue can only get O(n) insertion time. The usual binary heap implementation gets O(log(n)), and while esoteric implementations can get O(1), I think they lose on constant factor and still-O(log(n)) removal.

Comment: `List.add(E)` does this, it appends an item to the end of the list.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to let go of the ArrayList or the constant addition time. E.g, you could get an average O(1) insertion if you use a HashMap for each priority to store the data. But this assumes you know the amount of priorities ahead of time. If not, the insertion would probably be at least O(log #priorities), since you need to get to the right map.